# Array to string conversion in Realation.php

Tags: php, symfony, symfony1, php-7

I want to port the Symfony 1 framework to PHP7.
I am Stuck on this:

```
 /**
 * __toString
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString()
{
    $r[] = "<pre>";
    foreach ($this->definition as $k => $v) {
        if (is_object($v)) {
            $v = 'Object(' . get_class($v) . ')';
        }
        $r[] = $k . ' : ' .  $v;
    }
    $r[] = "</pre>";
    return implode("\n", $r);
}
```

In `$r[] = $k . ' : ' .  $v;` there is an error: `Array to string conversion`.
I tried to fix this with `$r[] = $k . ' : ' .  is_array($v) ? '' : $v;` but then the framework gives me following error:

```
500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should debug this to get `$v` type/value when error occurs

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error:
In `Collection.php` replace `$record->$relation['alias']` with `$record->{$relation['alias']}`.